# Dealing with GConf Error: No D-BUS daemon running error in Ubuntu 12.0.4 LTS

Tags: r, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, x11, gnome-terminal

I would like to run some R scripts in terminal on an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (no GUI) that is hosted as a virtual server inside a Windows 2008 Server. I log into the server through ssh and whenever I run R scripts or gnome-open command in the terminal I get the following error

```
(gnome-open:10138): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11
GConf Error: No D-BUS daemon running
```

I have tried everything including:

1.Installing Xvfb and configuring it.

2.Exporting display variable set in /etc/environment & ~/.bashrc

3.Trying to export dbus-launch to no avail

4.Getting & loading the session dbus id from file

X11 forwarding has been enabled

I need help dealing with this issue. Any ideas?

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
apt-get install dbus-x11
```

this helps me on a ubuntu 12.04 with X installed and the same error message.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).